# loading edit form only if GET var exists in database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

What my script currently does:

- grabs & cleans a $_GET['id']
- pulls all pre-existing data from TABLE for that id
- displays form populated with any pre-existing data
- SUBMIT sends form data to update script, adds all data to TABLE

What I want my script to do:

- grabs & cleans a $_GET['id']
- *pulls all possible (id)'s from TABLE* (this I know how to do)
- *checks that `$_GET['id']` is in array ID* (this I know how to do)
- *IF NOT, kill script, do not display form, and echo error message* (this I don't)
- *IF YES, proceed as normal*
- pulls all pre-existing data from TABLE for that id
- displays form populated with any pre-existing data
- SUBMIT sends form data to update script, adds all data to TABLE

Current script structure:

- php code
- html form with `<?php _ ?>` inserts for all values

I've tried to be a good lad and separate my code, and have largely succeeded. But that's left me with the problem that my html form displays whether the `$_GET['id']` is legit or not.

Could someone please help me set it up so that `if (!in_array($id, $allIDs))` prevents the form from displaying and tosses out an error instead?

Other than making the form an echoed HEREDOC, is there a way to control the display of that html?

Psuedocode is acceptable. I didn't bother posting my actual code because I didn't think the problem really merited such specificity. I can if need be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pulls all possible (id)'s from TABLE, checks that $_GET['id'] is in array ID (this I know how to do)

That's stupidly inefficient. You should ask the DB if it has a row with ID = $_GET['id'].

I'd show you *how* to do that if you show how you're currently doing DB queries.

> Other than making the form an echoed HEREDOC, is there a way to control the display of that html?

Well, this works, maybe surprisingly:

```
<?php
if ($should_show_form) {
?>
<form action="">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
} else {
    //do something else
}
?>
```

Comment: As you may have guessed, I am a beginner, and a self-taught one at that. Learning in this fashion is economical, but inevitably leads to great (and later, quite obvious) holes in one's knowledge & ability. Thank you for plugging two of them in one fell swoop: that I can query only for existence, and that I can put the html "in" the php code. I was visualizing it the other way - putting the php "in" the html. I feel like a catfish just swam into my gourd. Thank you!